# Won't DNS records reveal who Satoshi is?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto

Fine, we don't know who he is. I get that. But he **did** register bitcoin.org, and as a result had to use a credit card. So the original domain registrar must know who he is, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that Satoshi himself registered the domain with his or her own personal information, and/or used a credit card tied to his or her real name, then it is likely that the registrar maybe have knowledge of the real identity.

**HOWEVER**,

- It is not known if Satoshi used his or her real name to register.
- It is not known if Satoshi used his or her personal payment information when registering.
- It is unlikely that a registrar that specializes in privacy would ever divulge the above information or even its existence without a court order.
- It is possible that the registrar may not have retained records dating back to then, so it is possible that the above information was known but is no longer retrievable.

[DNSHistory.org](http://dnshistory.org/dns-records/bitcoin.org) began tracking bitcoin.org in early 2011, well after Satoshi exited. It does not track registrant information. [WhoisRequest.org](http://whoisrequest.org/history/) tracks NS back to September 2008, but only tracks nameserver changes. [Who.is](http://who.is/domain-history/bitcoin.org) yields the known fact that the domain was registered with the AnonymousSpeech registrar and the registrant information as [DigiRock](http://www.digirock.jp/aboutus.html), a Japanese domain registrar and hosting provider. This was likely a proxy registration.

Comment: To be clear, the domain name was registered with anonymousspeech which protects the registrant information. HOWEVER, the technical admin in the whois is Digi-rock, the japanese hosting provider. Normally the tech contact would also be anonymousspeech when just registering the domain. So somehow Satoshi registered it via or with a Digi-rock service, and checking their services it appears you need to be in Japan to purchase.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, who made you think that Satoshi registered it? Based on [this information](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=103369.0) there are a lot of speculation regarding this issue.

Secondly, if even he has registered something, why do you think it will be so easy to track back the identity? Sometimes people can use fake identities, proxy servers and anonymisers exist, people can sit in cafes in another city where they will never appear.

Comment: Well - he would have had to use a credit card. So although, he could have lied about his name, etc, there is a trail of who he is.

Comment: I do not know how is it in the rest of the world, but in UAE you can just buy a card and put some cash on it. No one asks you about your identity and you can pay with it.